# Different dates in SSRS report with same calculation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

So I've got what could be a very silly question, but for some reason my 'problem' isn't ***working***.

It's quite simple really. One of the fields in a SSRS tablix is a due date calculated by using the SQL function DateAdd:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Int(Fields!TMinus.Value) * 7), Parameters!StartDate.Value)
```

Where **TMinus** is a negative integer simulating weeks and **StartDate** being the date the activity started.

I'm calculating the same thing in VB.NET using this formula to set up the DueDate of an activity in a row cell:

```
Dim intTMinus As Integer = CInt(dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("TMinus").ToString)
CType(dataItem.FindControl("RlblDue"), RadLabel).Text = CDate(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (intTMinus * 7), dtStartDate)).ToString
```

The problem is that the SSRS report shows a DIFFERENT date than the Grid, even though I've used hardcoded values to attempt to find the culprit in the report.

This calculation in the report:

```
  =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Int(-40) * 7), '12/09/2016')
```

Shows the date: 07/12/2015 in the **Grid**, but 3/4/2016 on the **Report**

Answer (score 0):

Note `DateAdd` arguments data types have to be DateInterval, Double, and DateTime respectively. You are passing a string `'12/09/2016'` for the third argument but it requires a `DateTime`. By the way, strings in SSRS must be surrounded with double quotes.

After fix the expression, it should be like this:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Int(-40) * 7), CDATE("2016-09-12"))
```

Which returns: `07/12/2015` as your Grid in VB.

Note `CDATE("2016-09-12")` converts the date string in a `DateTime` value.

Check your parameter is set to `Date/Time` type.

[REFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Let me know if this helps.